# Find record older / newer than the current record in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a SQL statement that gives me a previous / next record.

My posts table has records that are either a blog post or a ships log (based on the column posts_isLog being either a 1 or 0).

I am using the following prepared statement to return the current ships log based on the date. The column post_createdOn is a date/time data type. I am using a like statement to match my passed date to the query as this is found via the URL so "shipslog/14th-April-2020". The date is changed to match the data so yyyy-mm-dd so no issues there.

```
//query
$this->db->query('SELECT * 
                  from posts 
                    INNER JOIN voyages ON posts.post_voyage = voyages.voyage_id 
                  WHERE post_createdOn LIKE :date 
                  AND post_isLog = 1 
                  AND post_live = 1');
//bind values
$this->db->bind(':date', '%'.$date.'%');
//get the results
$row = $this->db->single();
return $row;
```

I can't work out the SQL to use find the next / previous ships log based on the current record.

I think what I am looking to write is something like... "Select all from posts where post_createdOn is less than the current record's post_createdOn date".

I am trying

```
//query
$this->db->query('SELECT * 
                  from posts 
                  WHERE post_createdOn < :date 
                    AND post_isLog = 1 
                    AND post_live = 1');
//bind values
$this->db->bind(':date', '%'.$date.'%');
//get the results
$row = $this->db->single();
return $row;
```

But I know this isn't referring to the current record. Completely stumped!

This is the refering `$this->db->single();`

```
//get single record as an object
    public function single() {
      $this->execute();
      return $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
```

Comment: Second query is better but use `$this->db->bind(':date', '$date');` UYou are no longer doing a LIKE

Comment: Also `$this->db->single();` is not Vamilla PDO. So you might want to show us that code as well

Comment: By taking out the % from the query it returns rows, however it is returning the first record that is older not the next one in date order. E.g. record we are looking at was created 15/04/20 (id 9); next record in table (id 11) created 11/04/20, record (id 12) created 12/04/20. So we should really see record id 12 not 11???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the answers!

It seems I was nearly there after @RiggsFolly's help. I took out the % and the query returned a result. I needed to order the results as I was only returning the first row!

```
public function getPreviousLog($date) {
    //query
    $this->db->query('SELECT * 
                      from posts 
                      WHERE post_createdOn < :date 
                      AND post_isLog = 1 
                      AND post_live = 1 
                      ORDER BY post_createdOn DESC');
    //bind values
    $this->db->bind(':date', $date);
    //get the results
    $row = $this->db->single();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LAG and LEAD for this but it's a bit tedious if you have a lot of columns. Instead try:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY post_CreatedOn) rn
    FROM posts 
    WHERE 
      post_createdOn < :date AND 
      post_isLog = 1 AND 
      post_live = 1
)

SELECT * 
FROM
  cte curr
  LEFT JOIN cte next ON curr.rn+1 = next.rn
  LEFT JOIN cte prev ON curr.rn-1 = prev.rn
```

You don't seem to specify any partition - you just say that your table is one long stream of dated records and each record has a prev and a next according to the date. If there is some sort of notion that groups of columns belong together, put the thing that groups them into the row number as a PARTITION BY and also add it to the join ON clauses between prev curr and next

I'm not entirely clear on whether you want the "next" row if it it outside the date limit. Eg if you have two rows 2000-12-31 and 2001-01-01 and you set your date parameter to 2001-01-01 then the later record will be excluded as "current" but does it mean that the 2000-12-31 row should have a "next" that is null, or is the 2001-01-01 row

If it should (this query will not return it) take the predicate out of the CTE and put it in the main query WHERE, on curr.post_createdOn instead

---

If you're making some kind of pagination system, with one log per day and you want 3 rows, consider:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM posts 
    WHERE 
      post_isLog = 1 AND 
      post_live = 1
)

SELECT. * 
FROM cte
WHERE post_createdOn IN(
  SELECT MAX(post_createdOn) FROM cte WHERE post_createdOn < @date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT @date
  SELECT MIN(post_createdOn) FROM cte WHERE post_createdOn > @date
)
```